# Network and connectivity on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, driver

my PC does not frequently detect my WIFI network on the WIFI list, although it is detectable on my phone. So still suffer from this problem which does not allow me to connect to my PC.
[Description of my windows version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJSLx.png)
[Description of my network card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZhYS.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i should try to use Solve problems tool on windows. Sometimes solves problems.
If this doesnt work, check your drivers and if none of this options work, i would to replce your network card.